# How to display files with declared file extension in android

Tags: android

I am new to android java, Im trying to display only specified file types to my file explorer app. here is my code:

thank you!

```
if(file.getName().toString().endsWith(".webm") || file.getName().toString().endsWith(".mkv") || file.getName().toString().endsWith(".flv") || file.getName().toString().endsWith(".ogv") || file.getName().toString().endsWith(".ogg") || file.getName().toString().endsWith(".drc") || file.getName().toString().endsWith(".avi") || file.getName().toString().endsWith(".mov") || file.getName().toString().endsWith(".wmv") || file.getName().toString().endsWith(".mp4") || file.getName().toString().endsWith(".m4p") || file.getName().toString().endsWith(".mpg") || file.getName().toString().endsWith(".mpeg") || file.getName().toString().endsWith(".mpv") || file.getName().toString().endsWith(".mpe") || file.getName().toString().endsWith(".3gp")){
      for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
       File file = files[i];
       path.add(file.getPath());
       if (file.isDirectory())
        item.add(file.getName() + "/");
       else
        item.add(file.getName());
       }
      }
```

Comment: so, what is the question?

Comment: Are you facing any error ? If yes post your log here.

Comment: when I try to open the activity, it will force close.

Comment: the question is How will I make the file extension appear that putted there? The code that I used, is that correct?

Comment: First off, you'll want to change that mile long IF OR etc to a switch statement for readability. Second, you can use a MediaScanner to scan for specific file types in a folder if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: That is very wrong code. You throw away `file`. And add all without even looking.

Comment: @greenapps what should I do to make it right? I'm lost

Comment: You only need `if( file has wanted extension) { add file to array or list}`.

Comment: still cannot figure it out, I also tried putting the if statement inside the for. @greenapps